# 2 identfical sql queries w' diff params - only one requires temp table

Tags: sql, mysql, myisam

The only difference in these sql queries is the record_id param (it's how I page through entire result set).  The tables are myisam.  The first query performs well and the second is terribly slow.  Any idea why this would be?

This query works fine

```
explain select r.record_id, r.oai_datestamp, r.format_id, r.status,  x.xml,  max(u.date_updated) as date_updated 
from  marcnormalization.records r, 
   marcnormalization.records_xml x, 
   marcnormalization.record_updates u 
where r.record_id = x.record_id 
  and (r.record_id > 1802000 or 1802000 is null) 
  and r.record_id = u.record_id 
  and (u.date_updated > '1960-10-19 10:18:52.0' or '1960-10-19 10:18:52.0' is null) 
  and u.date_updated <= '2010-10-07 10:18:52.0'
group by u.record_id 
order by u.record_id 
limit 1000;
```

this query is super slow (creates a temporary table)

```
explain select r.record_id, r.oai_datestamp, r.format_id, r.status,  x.xml,  max(u.date_updated) as date_updated 
from  marcnormalization.records r, 
   marcnormalization.records_xml x, 
   marcnormalization.record_updates u 
where r.record_id = x.record_id 
  and (r.record_id > 2202000 or 2202000 is null) 
  and r.record_id = u.record_id 
  and (u.date_updated > '1960-10-19 10:18:52.0' or '1960-10-19 10:18:52.0' is null) 
  and u.date_updated <= '2010-10-07 10:18:52.0'
group by u.record_id 
order by u.record_id 
limit 1000;
```

**update: I've gotten through my issue by changing from**

```
group by u.record_id 
order by u.record_id
```

to

```
group by r.record_id 
order by r.record_id
```

So, it's kind of a moot point now, but I'm still curious as to the initial question.

Answer (score 1):

i think that this case related with your connection sort area also.
You can increase this are for session.
try like this;

mysql> select @@max_heap_table_size;

mysql> SET SESSION max_heap_table_size=19777216;

after that execute the query.

Baris Akverdi

Answer (score 0):

What about :

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT r.record_id, r.oai_datestamp, r.format_id, r.status,  x.xml,  max(u.date_updated) as date_updated 
FROM marcnormalization.records_xml x
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM marcnormalization.records WHERE record_id > 1802000) r
ON r.record_id = x.record_id
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM marcnormalization.record_updates WHERE date_updated BETWEEN '1960-10-19 10:18:52.0' AND '2010-10-07 10:18:52.0') u
ON r.record_id = u.record_id
group by u.record_id ASC
limit 1000;
```

I think it can be faster ?